# Docusign API Signature Request - UNSPECIFIED_ERROR - ErrorCode: 1, ErrorReason: An Error Occured

Tags: docusignapi

I signed up for DocuSign demo account and I'm trying to submit a signature request but keep getting "Unspecified Error" response. I'm using SOAP API and PHP. I would appreciate any hints on possible reasons causing this error message. My sample request below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsa:Action>http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:To>https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx</wsa:To>
    <wsa:MessageID>uudi:e3be95a2-819d-9760-bdec-b73b2c99933b</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2015-06-10T22:58:06Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2015-06-10T23:03:06Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>[INTEGRATOR_KEY_HERE]USERNAME_KEY_HERE</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD_HERE</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>0jmJAY+vX41kkU5y5clzyp2goK3prYljWKIs8AR+5tE=</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2015-06-10T22:58:06Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
      <ns1:EnvelopeInformation>
        <ns1:AccountId>ACCOUNT_ID_HERE</ns1:AccountId>
        <ns1:EmailBlurb>Some message</ns1:EmailBlurb>
        <ns1:Subject>Some subject</ns1:Subject>
      </ns1:EnvelopeInformation>
      <ns1:CompositeTemplates>
        <ns1:CompositeTemplate>
          <ns1:InlineTemplates>
            <ns1:InlineTemplate>
              <ns1:Sequence>1</ns1:Sequence>
              <ns1:Envelope>
                <ns1:AccountId>ACCOUNT_ID_HERE</ns1:AccountId>
                <ns1:Recipients>
                  <ns1:Recipient>
                    <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID>
                    <ns1:UserName>Joe Doe</ns1:UserName>
                    <ns1:Email>email@example.com</ns1:Email>
                    <ns1:Type>Signer</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:AccessCode xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ns1:RequireIDLookup>false</ns1:RequireIDLookup>
                    <ns1:RoutingOrder>1</ns1:RoutingOrder>
                    <ns1:RoleName>Applicant</ns1:RoleName>
                  </ns1:Recipient>
                  <ns1:Recipient>
                    <ns1:ID>2</ns1:ID>
                    <ns1:UserName>Jane Doe</ns1:UserName>
                    <ns1:Email>email2@example.com</ns1:Email>
                    <ns1:Type>Signer</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:AccessCode xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ns1:RequireIDLookup>false</ns1:RequireIDLookup>
                    <ns1:RoutingOrder>2</ns1:RoutingOrder>
                    <ns1:RoleName>Co-Applicant</ns1:RoleName>
                  </ns1:Recipient>
                </ns1:Recipients>
                <ns1:Tabs>
                  <ns1:Tab>
                    <ns1:RecipientID>1</ns1:RecipientID>
                    <ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                      <ns1:AnchorTabString>{SIGNATURE}</ns1:AnchorTabString>
                      <ns1:XOffset>0</ns1:XOffset>
                      <ns1:YOffset>0</ns1:YOffset>
                      <ns1:Unit>Pixels</ns1:Unit>
                      <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                    </ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns1:Type>SignHere</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:TabLabel>Signature</ns1:TabLabel>
                  </ns1:Tab>
                  <ns1:Tab>
                    <ns1:RecipientID>1</ns1:RecipientID>
                    <ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                      <ns1:AnchorTabString>{INITIAL}</ns1:AnchorTabString>
                      <ns1:XOffset>0</ns1:XOffset>
                      <ns1:YOffset>0</ns1:YOffset>
                      <ns1:Unit>Pixels</ns1:Unit>
                      <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                    </ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns1:Type>InitialHere</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:TabLabel>Initial</ns1:TabLabel>
                  </ns1:Tab>
                  <ns1:Tab>
                    <ns1:RecipientID>1</ns1:RecipientID>
                    <ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                      <ns1:AnchorTabString>{SIGNDATE}</ns1:AnchorTabString>
                      <ns1:XOffset>0</ns1:XOffset>
                      <ns1:YOffset>0</ns1:YOffset>
                      <ns1:Unit>Pixels</ns1:Unit>
                      <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                    </ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns1:Type>DateSigned</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:TabLabel>Date</ns1:TabLabel>
                  </ns1:Tab>
                  <ns1:Tab>
                    <ns1:RecipientID>2</ns1:RecipientID>
                    <ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                      <ns1:AnchorTabString>{COSIGNATURE}</ns1:AnchorTabString>
                      <ns1:XOffset>0</ns1:XOffset>
                      <ns1:YOffset>0</ns1:YOffset>
                      <ns1:Unit>Pixels</ns1:Unit>
                      <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                    </ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns1:Type>SignHere</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:TabLabel>Signature</ns1:TabLabel>
                  </ns1:Tab>
                  <ns1:Tab>
                    <ns1:RecipientID>2</ns1:RecipientID>
                    <ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                      <ns1:AnchorTabString>{COINITIAL}</ns1:AnchorTabString>
                      <ns1:XOffset>0</ns1:XOffset>
                      <ns1:YOffset>0</ns1:YOffset>
                      <ns1:Unit>Pixels</ns1:Unit>
                      <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                    </ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns1:Type>InitialHere</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:TabLabel>Initial</ns1:TabLabel>
                  </ns1:Tab>
                  <ns1:Tab>
                    <ns1:RecipientID>2</ns1:RecipientID>
                    <ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                      <ns1:AnchorTabString>{COSIGNDATE}</ns1:AnchorTabString>
                      <ns1:XOffset>0</ns1:XOffset>
                      <ns1:YOffset>0</ns1:YOffset>
                      <ns1:Unit>Pixels</ns1:Unit>
                      <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                    </ns1:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns1:Type>DateSigned</ns1:Type>
                    <ns1:TabLabel>Date</ns1:TabLabel>
                  </ns1:Tab>
                </ns1:Tabs>
              </ns1:Envelope>
            </ns1:InlineTemplate>
          </ns1:InlineTemplates>
          <ns1:Document>
            <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:Name>Account Withdrawal Request</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:PDFBytes>BASE64ENCODED_DOC_HERE</ns1:PDFBytes>
            <ns1:TransformPdfFields>true</ns1:TransformPdfFields>
            <ns1:FileExtension>pdf</ns1:FileExtension>
          </ns1:Document>
        </ns1:CompositeTemplate>
      </ns1:CompositeTemplates>
      <ns1:ActivateEnvelope>false</ns1:ActivateEnvelope>
    </ns1:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you seen the open source [SOAP SDK](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK) that's up on GitHub?  That has sample projects and code for PHP (and other language stacks), try using the sample code for `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms` and see if that works for you.  If so it's an issue with your code or how you are building the envelope.  If not, something else is going on (like firewall blocking your request or something similar).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to resolve the issue. My document was an invalid PDF. It would be nice if DocuSign could catch this properly - the unspecified error message is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that DocuSign's API should return a more user friendly message here.  For the benefit of the community though, in this case it looks like it was an invalid PDF that was being sent.  For future requests that receive the dreaded `UNSPECIFIED_ERROR` start by ensuring you're sending a valid document.